# Get element offset relative to grand-...-grand--parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I would like to get the position of `#mainChildElement` relative to `.grand-grand-grand-parent` using javascript/jquery. I tried doing `$('#mainChildElement').offset().top` however this just returns the offset relative to the immediate parent.

Would I have to recursively find the position by iterating through the tree and sum the top offset of each element until I hit the `.grand-grand-grand-parent` or is there a more elegant solution?

```
<div class="grand-grand-grand-parent">
    <div class="grand-grand-parent">
        <div class="grand-parent">
            <div class="parent">
                <div class="child-element">
                    Content goes here!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grand-parent">
            <div class="parent">
                <div class="child-element">
                    Content goes here!
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="parent">
                <div class="child-element">
                    Content goes here!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grand-grand-parent">
        <div class="grand-parent">
            <div class="parent">
                <div class="child-element">
                    Content goes here!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grand-parent">
            <div class="parent">
                <div id="mainChildElement" class="child-element">
                    Where am I?!
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="parent">
                <div class="child-element">
                    Content goes here!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"I tried doing $('#mainChildElement').offset().top however this just returns the offset relative to the immediate parent."* No, it returns the offset relative to the *document*. There's also `position` which returns the offset relative to the *nearest offset parent* (which may not be the immediate parent). Usually you want one of those two things; what is your use-case for the offset relative to a specific ancestor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution is to calculate the `.offset()`s difference of the element with the reference you want to use.

Doc about `.offset()`: https://api.jquery.com/offset/

> Description: Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the document.

```js
var ref_top = $('#gggp').offset().top;
var child_top = $('#mainChildElement').offset().top;
var diff = child_top - ref_top;

console.log('Reference:', ref_top + 'px');
console.log('Child:', child_top + 'px');
console.log('Difference:', diff + 'px');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gggp" class="grand-grand-grand-parent">
  <div class="grand-grand-parent">
    <div class="grand-parent">
      <div class="parent">
        <div class="child-element">
          Content goes here!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grand-parent">
      <div class="parent">
        <div class="child-element">
          Content goes here!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="parent">
        <div class="child-element">
          Content goes here!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grand-grand-parent">
    <div class="grand-parent">
      <div class="parent">
        <div class="child-element">
          Content goes here!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grand-parent">
      <div class="parent">
        <div id="mainChildElement" class="child-element">
          Where am I?!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="parent">
        <div class="child-element">
          Content goes here!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You were correct for the question I asked! However, I recognised that the environment I was working in (Sharepoint) had wrapped the page scroll inside a div (and not the window) and thus changing the offset().top for the element whenever a scroll event occurred inside the div wrapper. This made me reconstruct how I would use the offset().top variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can get their position relative to the screen with `getClientBoundingRect()` and measure the difference. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.grand-grand-grand-parent');
const child = document.querySelector('#mainChildElement');
console.log(child.getBoundingClientRect().top - parent.getBoundingClientRect().top);
```

```html
<div class="grand-grand-grand-parent">
    <div class="grand-grand-parent">
        <div class="grand-parent">
            <div class="parent">
                <div class="child-element">
                    Content goes here!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grand-parent">
            <div class="parent">
                <div class="child-element">
                    Content goes here!
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="parent">
                <div class="child-element">
                    Content goes here!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grand-grand-parent">
        <div class="grand-parent">
            <div class="parent">
                <div class="child-element">
                    Content goes here!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grand-parent">
            <div class="parent">
                <div id="mainChildElement" class="child-element">
                    Where am I?!
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="parent">
                <div class="child-element">
                    Content goes here!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```